# Fit navigation drawer icon to toolbar in android

Tags: android

[image]

Hello,
I am working in android, in my app i am using navigation drawer and i have changed the using navigation icon as in the image. But that image is not getting fit to toolbar. as you see in image automatically margin is felt around the icon. i don't want that margin, that icon should fit to toolbar
below is my code
Please help

```
Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });
    // Drawer object Assigned to the view
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer,toolbar, R.string.a, R.string.b) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

        }
    }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
    Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menuicon); //this is navigation icon
```

Answer (score 0):

The default action bar will not allow you to cover the complete area. Instead, you can use custom Toolbar. In that case, you will have to handle clicks in the home menu etc by yourself.

Refer the following design for toolbar:

*layout/custom_app_bar.xml*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    ... >

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            ...
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/your_icon" />

        <TextView
            ...
            android:text="title" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Include this toolbar in your activity layout as

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_app_bar"/>
```